# Android Listview keeps old items after adapter changes

Tags: android, list, listview, listadapter

I try to change the content of a Listview in Android. After that I want the list to be redrawn. Unfortunately the list elements change, but the old items are displayed in the background. If there are less items in the new list it seems like the old items are still part of the list, as they are still displayed, even though they are not clickable. If I jump out of the app via the Android Taskmanager and afterwards open the app again, the list gets displayed correctly! 
Therefore I think it must be a problem with refresh.

How do I try to achieve it:

As the complete content changes I create a new adapter that I pass to the ListView. In my code "favorites" is the new Array that I pass to the adapter. I also try to clear the list and invalidate it. all of this happens in the UI thread (onPostExecute of AsyncTask)

```
    MyAdapter newAdapter = new MyAdapter(
            context, favorites);
    MyAdapter current_adapter = (MyAdapter) myList.getAdapter(); 
    if((current_adapter!=null)){
    current_adapter.clear();}

    myList.setAdapter(null); //inserted this because of answers, but with no effect.
    myList.setAdapter(newAdapter);
    myList.invalidateViews();
```

The clear method of the adapter:

```
    public void clear(){
    items.clear();
    notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

As you can see I tried all of the solutions to similar problems her on stackoverflow. Unfortunately nothing worked...

Thanks in advance for any ideas how to solve this.

Edit:

I have also tried to set the adapter null before passing the new one, also with no effect.
.setAdapter(null);

Also if I open the keyboard by clicking in a editText, the screen refreshs and the list is displayed correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried `myList.setAdapter(null);` ?

Comment: was it finally the solution? Doesnt work for me and I have the same problem.

Answer (score 2):

I solved the problem by filling the remaining space under the list with a layout with more `layout_weight` than the `ListView`. This way the "extra" lines are hidden.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/main_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/transparent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/main_list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/aux_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@color/transparent"
        android:orientation="vertical" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: This worked for me perfectly, it seems that Android is not cleaning properly the 'trash' after the control shrinks. So whatever was in it but is now outside its stays there until covered by something else. Expanding container does the job

Comment: This worked for me perfectly. All others not worked. Thanks man

Answer (score 2):

I tried that and I discovered HardwareAcceleration has to be set to TRUE (what is also default value) in application tag in your manifest file. Otherwise listView will keep old non-clickable items in its background during typing.

```
android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
```

Answer (score 1):

First clear the data. I think it's `favorites` or `items` or whatever. and notify the adapter in this way.

```
items.clear();
((MyAdapter) myList.getAdapter()).notifyDataSetChanged();
MyAdapter newAdapter = new MyAdapter(context, favorites);
myList.setAdapter(newAdapter);
myList.invalidate();
```